# Как передать файл из android приложения на сервер?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Добрый день. Имеем php страничку с возможностью ручной загрузки файлов через компьютер. Что мы не имеем, но хотим иметь: нужно из android приложения передавать файл на эту самую страницу (как будто пользователь выбрал файл и нажал "Загрузить" через комп). А далее работать с этим файлом по обычному. После того, как работа с файлом была совершена, вернуть юзеру сообщение, мол файл загружен. 
Как нам это реализовать? Что гуглить? Направьте, пожалуйста, в нужное русло.

Answer (score 1):

Если что гуглить: запрос POST, [multipart/form-data](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data) и как сформировать такой (POST) [запрос в Андройде](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553507/multipart-form-data-construction-with-android).